# Popup Orientation Change

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller, screen-orientation

In this application starting onwards Portrait mode.

[image]

.[image]

> code snippet

```
NSInteger heightOne;
    NSInteger heightTwo;
    NSInteger imgV;
    CGRect Bounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (Bounds.size.height == 568) {
    // code for 4-inch screen
    heightOne = 480+38;
    heightTwo = 240+38;//370
    imgV = 360;

} else {
    // code for 3.5-inch screen
    heightOne = 480;
    heightTwo = 240;//330
    imgV = 310;

}

UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(00, 00,320,heightOne)];
firstView.opaque = NO;
firstView.tag = 1000;
firstView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
[self.view addSubview:firstView];



UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250,imgV,50,50)];
img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Zoom.jpg"];
[firstView addSubview:img];

UIView *secondView= [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,heightOne)];
[secondView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[firstView addSubview:secondView];

UIView *thirdView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,60,290,heightTwo)];//30
[thirdView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
thirdView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f;
thirdView.layer.borderWidth = 4.0f;
thirdView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:0.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
[secondView insertSubview:thirdView atIndex:0];    


///////////////////////////// Creating custom close button ////////////////////////////////


UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(287,48,30,30)];//24
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Close-Gr.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissOverViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[secondView insertSubview:button aboveSubview:thirdView];
secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
                 }];


[thirdView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

}

**here i need only popup rotation** .Any Ref link or suggestion ,it's really appreciated.

Comment: set the  frame of your popup in orientation method when your rotate device in landscape

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return NO from

```
 - (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Handle device rotation via Local Notifications :-

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And rotate the view as you want :-

```
 self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
 self.theView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(-90));
```

May this help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please register for rotation notifications in viewdidlod

- (void)viewDidLoad

{

```
UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]   statusBarOrientation];

if (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    [self willRotateToLandscape];
else
    [self willRotateToPortrait];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willRotateToLandscape) name:@"Interface will rotate to landscape" object:nil];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willRotateToPortrait) name:@"Interface will rotate to portrait" object:nil];
```

}

//then adjust the popup view size in the following functions.
- (void)willRotateToLandscape
{
}
- (void)willRotateToPortrait
{
}